# image "pyimage1" doesn't exist even if master is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-photoimage

I made a script with tkinter which worked until I include it into another script. Both are making their own window tkinter and with all I read on this error it seems that the error is because the fact that there are two windows. Furthermore, on all I read, the error was because the master was not defined but in my script it is. Here is the error with the script:

```
File "C:\Users\Noam\pythonProject1\ui.py", line 95, in afficher_images
    button = tk.Button(master=frame, image=i[1][0])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Noam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2706, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Noam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2628, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

so my photoimage is located in i[1][0] . I tried to change the code to make the PhotoImage directly by creating the button and it always doesn't work but this time it is pyimage5 and not 1.

Comment: print the variable 1, it should give you an array representation of what's in there. I suspect that the image is in i[0][0] and not i[1][0]

Comment: @EricYang, in i[1] there is the link of the image and when i print i[1] i have this tuple `(<PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x000001AF9AAEDF10>, <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x000001AF99AD6BD0>, (0, 0))` so  the image than I search is well in i[1][0]

Comment: If the problem is that you have multiple instances of `Tk()`, and you somehow don't want to use the obvious fix of *not* having multiple instances of `Tk()` (using `Toplevel()` instead for additional windows), the place where `master=` might fix things is on the image objects, rather than the widgets.

Comment: @jasonharper Ok thanks for your reply with TopLevel() it is working